Query a table in an External Connection in BigQuery
I'm attempting to view columns of a table in an External Connection in BigQuery.  However, I'm running into an issue due to one of the columns using UUID, which isn't supported in BQ.  I can CAST() the column, but I still can't see what other columns exist in the table.
What's the best way to get a list of all columns in this case?
I'm attempting to view columns of a table in an External Connection in BigQuery.  However, I'm running into an issue due to one of the columns using UUID, which isn't supported in BQ.  I can CAST() the column, but I still can't see what other columns exist in the table.
What's the best way to get a list of all columns in this case?
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("table.employee.us.data", "SELECT * FROM data_table";");

which throws the error: Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY PostgreSQL type UUID in column id is not supported in BigQuery. You can cast it to a supported type by PostgreSQL CAST() function. at [1:15]
I also attempted using the EXCEPT() clause, but BQ still didn't like it:
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("table.employee.us.data", "SELECT * EXCEPT(ID) FROM data_table";");

which throws the error: Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY Failed to get query schema from PostgreSQL server, prepare statement failed. Error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ID" LINE 1: SELECT * EXCEPT (ID) FROM data_table; /* Federated ... ^ at [1:15]
I'm ultimately trying to get a list of columns in this table

Could you try to use the query mentioned in the documentation to get the list of all the columns of the table. Let me know if this helps you or not?
